# Dynamic Validation through Google Apps Script

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new learner in Google Apps Script and need help in this.

I have a list of names of 10,000 individuals in Sheet1!A3:A.

In front of these people I have a list (in Sheet1!B3:B) of names of companies in which each of these people work.

The names in A3:A list is non-unique because people tend to have same name.

The list in B3:B is also non-unique because many people work in the same company.

I need to set validation in C3:D  in Sheet2 (not Sheet1) in such a way that if my users enter a person name, say Mr. X, from the above Sheet1!A3:A list in C3 of Sheet2!C3:C, then in D3 of Sheet2!D3:D it gives the validation/drop-down list of ONLY those companies in which people with Mr. X name work.

And, additionally, and if possible, if my users enter a company name, say XYZ Inc., from the above Sheet1!B3:B list in D3 of Sheet2!D3:D, then in C3 of Sheet2!C3:C it gives the validation/drop-down list of ONLY those individuals who work in XYZ Inc.

I assume that spreadsheet function/formula alone cannot achieve this, and one has to take the help of G.A.S.

Comment: You should take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613497/vlookup-all-the-values-matching-the-search-term-instead-of-just-one) where Scott Craner's response might help you (using of query formula)

Comment: @Pierre-MarieRichard thanx for your quick comment. I have gone through that SO post but it is something else; what i am looking for is - generation of a Dynamic Validation/drop-down list (through Google Apps Script).

Comment: Maybe you could bring a piece of exemple, code, something you've already done, so we could help you ?
Also, you can use the query to get your element and create a dropdown menu with this elements.